# Switching between view mode and edit mode in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best practice to switch between View and Edit Mode in Android? As example, I provided a screenshot of the Google Calendar application.

Should theses screen combined in one view? Or should one use two different Activities?

[image: View vs. Edit mode]

Comment: Either approach would be fine. Whether you do this as one activity, one activity plus two fragments, or two activities, is really up to you. Different developers may have different opinions as to which one they prefer, but there's no requirement that you implement this UI using any particular mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general good practice in this case. The choise depends on the overall number and type of differences between the two screens.

If there are major differences in layouts for example, use 2 Activities for better support later.

If only some view properties differ in the two modes, use 1 activity with some logic that handles the property values.

Make your decision based on the time you will need to support, scale and edit each view later on.